# android custom list view adapter doesnt update number of views in getView

Tags: android, listview, filter, dataset, adapter

I have a listView with a custom adapter. 
I have an edit text view in my activity where the user can type to filter the content on the list view.

Lets say I have two items on the list view. After doing the filter, the ArrayList is reduced to one element.
The problem is that the getView method is still executed for the two previous rows.

Here is my code.

ListActivity:

```
public class TeamsListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();
    private TeamsListAdapter teamsListAdapter = null;
    private EditText searchInput = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.teams_list);

        // get association id from the intent.
        int afId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("afId");
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "id_association =" + afId);

        // get the teams from the association.
        this.teams = TeamsDAO.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .getTeamsByAssociation(afId);


        // inits the list adapter
        teamsListAdapter = new TeamsListAdapter(this, teams);

        setListAdapter(teamsListAdapter);

        // gets the search input view
        searchInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.teams_list_search_box);
        searchInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Teams search: " + s.toString());
                teamsListAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);             
            }
        });

    }


}
```

**My adapter**

```
public class TeamsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Team> implements Filterable {

    private ArrayList<Team> teams = null;
    private Context context = null;

    public TeamsListAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<Team> objects) {

        super(context, R.layout.teams_list_row, objects);

        this.context = context;
        this.teams = objects;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.teams_list_row, null);
        }

            Team t = teams.get(position);
            if (t != null) {

                TextView txtTeamName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.teams_list_team_name);

                txtTeamName.setText(t.getName());

                ImageView ivTeamLogo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.teams_list_team_logo);
                ivTeamLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.af_braga);
            }



        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                  Log.d(Constants.TAG, "**** Search RESULTS for: " + constraint);
                   teams = (ArrayList<Team>) results.values;
                   Log.d(Constants.TAG,"size:"+teams.size());
                   TeamsListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "**** PERFORM TEAK FILTERING for: " + constraint);
                ArrayList<Team> filteredResults = getFilteredResults(constraint);

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                results.values = filteredResults;

                return results;
            }

            /**
             * filters the teamsList 
             * @param constraint String The text to search
             * @return ArrayList<Team>
             */
            private ArrayList<Team> getFilteredResults(CharSequence constraint) {
                ArrayList<Team> teams = TeamsListAdapter.this.teams;
                ArrayList<Team> filteredTeams = new ArrayList<Team>();
                for(int i=0;i< teams.size();i++){
                    if(teams.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())){
                        filteredTeams.add(teams.get(i));
                    }
                }

                return filteredTeams;
            }
        };

    }
}
```

**Clarification of the problem.**

1.Let´s say my list starts showing two elements. 
2. The user inserts some text in the edit text to filter the list content which results in a updated arrayList with only one element who matches the query.
3. After called the notifyDataSetChanged the getView still is called like there was two rows in the dataset resulting in IndexOutOfBoundsException when executing Team t = teams.get(position) becuase the arrayList has only one element now so when position = 1 => the get(postion) fails.

Hope its clear now.

Comment: You have to be more specific about your issue

Comment: I have added some more details about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I fix my problem.
I needed to override a couple of methods in my adapter like this.

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return teams.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Team getItem(int position) {
        return teams.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return teams.get(position).getId();
    }
```

Now i have discoreved a problem with my search implementation. Because i am updating the original dataset the search only works one time. If I try to go back to original list i cant because my original data array has been modified. Easy to solve with with a database query instead of filtering the array list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need

> teams = (ArrayList) results.values;

in publishResults function.

Comment: no I need it. Without that line the dataset is not updated with only the filtered values.

Comment: yes, you need that line in order to publish the results(filtered values).